# Cant seem to connect the JDBC sql server driver to java eclipse project

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, jdbc, driver

I'm trying to setup the connect from my sql server database to my project but when i try to compile it  i get:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc.odbc:login_DSN
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at SelfPractice.main(SelfPractice.java:13)
```

I'm very much new to this. i went to controlPanel>adminstrive tools>data sources and there added a data source called login_DSN .  i've looked in older posts and they say to include the driver jar file in class path which i think i did(i downloaded the jdbc driver from microsoft website and loaded it to a 'referenced library' in eclipose, but i still get this error message.
How do i solve my driver problem?

Comment: It is `jdbc:odbc:login_DSN` (note the colon instead of a period between jdbc and odbc). But you should seriously consider switching to the SQL Server JDBC driver instead of using the jdbc odbc bridge which is really crappy.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked! i can't believe it was that easy, i have been trying to make it work for the past 3 hours and all it was , was a simple syntax error. Now i just need to figure out how to use the sql server jdbc

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add mysql driver to eclipse project classpath you need to follow these steps:
1. Go to *Project Explorer* Window of Eclipse, Right click on the project, select *Properties*.
2. Click on *Java Build Path* from list of properties and then select *Libraries* tab
3. Click on *Add External JARs* button to add mysql_connector.jar(which you have downloaded earlier) to your project's classpath.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is exactly what i did, but for some reason it's still doesn't seem to work